# ¿Cómo eliminar items con AJAX y mostrar los resultados por pantalla?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Tengo una lista de items que cargo con un .getJSON().

```
$.getJSON('http://api.com/api',function(data){
console.log(data);
cont = 0;
$.each(data,function(){
    item = data[cont].item;
    $('#list').append('hola.'+item);
    cont++;
});
});
```

Al clic en la class `.delete` se borra de la base de datos correctamente, y al completarse la consulta `".done()"` se recarga toda la pagina. Me gustaría que en vez de recargar de nuevo toda la página sólo se eliminara el item que se ha borrado y ya no se vea por pantalla.

```
$(function() {
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
var data_del = $("#delete").serialize();
$.ajax({
    data: data_del,
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://api.com/api2
})
.done(function(){
    location.reload();
});
return false;
});
});
```

Supongo que hay un método para que no tenga que volver a cargar toda la página cada vez que elimino un item.

He provado con `remove()`, pero no es el resultado que esperaba tampoco.

Comment: ¿Sobre qué elemento estás llamando `remove()`?, ¿qué pasa cuando lo haces, obtienes algún error?

Comment: No se que parámetros poner en el remove para que solo se elimine el último, y no todos. A mi se me borraban todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resuelto mi problema, por si a alguien tiene el mismo y le interesa:
Simplemente he puesto una variable:

```
var item = $(this);
```

Y después he borrado el parent:

```
item.parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
$(function() {
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
Var ítem = $(this);
var data_del = $("#delete").serialize();
$.ajax({
    data: data_del,
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://api.com/api2"
})
.done(function(){
    Ítem.delete();
});
return false;
});
});
```

Esto siempre que .delete sea el ítem que quieres borrar...

El elemento this hace referencia al que ha llamado a la función de evento.

Comment: Esto lo que me hace es borrar sólo el botón de borrar, no todo el ítem.

Comment: Como digo en el ejemplo esto borra el elemento que lo llama, es decir te borra el botón de borrar de ese ítem verdad? Si es así tendrías que buscar desde this con parent hasta el elemento que quieres borrar. De todas formas ayudaría a tu problema que pusieras el html que forma tus ítems y tus botones de borrado.

Comment: Si, me ha ayudado tu respuesta, ya lo había resuelto, he cogido el parent y lo he borrado, debajo puedes verlo. Gracias :)